# How to change the url address using jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

Its like My current url address is

```
http://localhost/foldername/index.php
```

and i wanna show this as `http://localhost/foldername` is it possible with jquery/JS without using `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to making a pretty URL:

1. if you load the "ugly" URL, redirect to the "pretty" URL
2. if you load the "pretty" URL, serve the right content

JS can help with (1), because it can see the current URL, and send the browser somewhere else.

For (2), though, you need something on the server-side, because when the browser requests `http://localhost/categoryname`, the server needs to know what to send it.

This is what `mod_rewrite` is for. Note that `.htaccess` is just a file you can put Apache configuration in, not the name of the configuration itself; it's commonly used on shared hosts where you don't have access to the core Apache config.

`mod_rewrite` can be complicated, but it doesn't need to be. Don't be scared, and don't try to find an exotic workaround which will end up more complicated than modifying a few examples of `RewriteRule` found online. :)

Comment: now i know its impossible without .htaccess

may i know how .htaccess do that? im newbie and dont know how to do that

Comment: Just look around online for basically any introduction to mod_rewrite. This is about as simple as rules get.

Comment: hmm thnx a lot for yr help

Answer (score 1):

A simple Javascript will be sufficient for this:

```
if ((n=location.href.indexOf("/index.php")) > -1)
   location.assign(location.href.substring(0, n));
```